# Cropping image with ImageScience

Tags: ruby, image-processing, sinatra, image-science

[ImageScience](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ImageScience.html) is cool and light. I am using it in my sinatra app. But I can't understand how can I crop image with not square form and how can I make thumbnail with two dimensions.

As I found on ImageScience site:

```
ImageScience.with_image(file) do |img|
  img.cropped_thumbnail(100) do |thumb|
    thumb.save "#{file}_cropped.png"
  end

  img.thumbnail(100) do |thumb|
    thumb.save "#{file}_thumb.png"
  end

  img.resize(100, 150) do |img2|
    img2.save "#{file}_resize.png"
  end
end
```

I can crop thumb and resize thumb only with ONE dimension but I want to use two, as in RMagick. For example I want to crop 100x200px box from image, or I want to make thumbnail  with width or height not bigger then 300 (width) or 500 (height) pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I've looked into ImageScience sources and found great method `with_crop(left, top, right, bottom)` which helped me with my problem.

http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/image_science/ImageScience.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [Devil](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/the-devil-image-library-for-ruby/) instead:

```
Devil.with_image("horse.png") do |img|
    img.crop(0, 0, 100, 100)
    img.resize2(500, 500)
    img.save("horse_resized.jpg", :quality => 85)
end
```

Comment: I can use ImageMagick, or Rmagick instead. But never heard about Devil. Thanks. I'll look on it

Comment: @fl00r, Devil is light-weight (like ImageScience). ImageMagick/Rmagick i steer way clear of, they're bulky, slow, hard to install...ugh

Comment: Yes. RMagick is real monster. Devil looks feature-enough for me.